# Asynchronous and RealTime Connection in DLLImport

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, dllimport, bridge

Sorry if this is a little beginner's question...

But I did not find anything anywhere!

> I know how to call a function inside the c++ dll and run it from C# , **DLLImport** and stuffs then I have no problem with it.

**But is there any way to do this in the opposite way and the same connection [DLLImport]?**

> I wrote a C++/CLI bridge and it's doing the opposite job with sending
>   C++ command to C# but I need it in same connection and same apps.

**Let me explain more :**

- I have a server is developed in **Python and C++**
- My server use a complex and signature security method to exchange data from client and itself
- As you are most aware of it , **C# has very low security** and I can't risk on users data by using it , then I created a C++ Client Service **[ a DLL ]** with two general functions :

> **1. Real-Time Data Receiving**
>
> **2. Real-Time Data Sending**

- I use C# as my application UI.
- I need to execute command from C++ Client .dll by C# ...

> Now , We can send data from **C# User-Interface** to **C++ Client** by **DLLImport** 
>   But how can we call C# when server sends a message to the C++ client and in the other side , never kill the sockets connection?!

**is there any way to make C#/C++ exchange in two-way connection ?**

- And remember it can't be done with a ticking checker clock! Because it may require 1,000 requests at the same time :)

I appreciate any help!

Comment: @ÖöTiib thank you I'm checking it out right now